# Generate specific error code for missing function input

Tags: r, function, if-statement, error-handling

I have two functions similar to the following. The first detects if a variable is blank while the second will generate something that isn't relevant to this question. I want the second function to output the following specific error messages in the conditions stipulated with the "if" in it:

```
is.blank <- function(x) is.na(x) | x == ""

generate_something <- function(n, m, roll) {
  if (is.blank(n)) {
     stop("Missing number of blocks.")
  }
  if (is.blank(m)) {
     stop("Missing M number.")
  }
  if (is.blank(roll) && m > 27) {
     stop("Missing roll where relevant.")
  }
}
```

However, R doesn't play well with this when I try to run generate_something() with any inputs missing. Instead, it will give me its own error message:

```
Error in generate_something(m = 34, roll = 1) :
 argument "n" is missing with no default
```

However, if I define the function with all inputs equal to NULL, then this does not solve the problem either. What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: @SamR, Yes my apolgies. I have editd my typo

Comment: Note that R has a built in function called `missing` to check for missing arguments. Note that "missing" is different than "blank". You have to not be missing before you can check if it's value is blank.

Comment: If you don't provide `n` at all, e.g. `generate_something(m = 34, roll = 1)`, you will not even get to the first line of your function to check if `n` is blank. That's what's happening in your case. If you want to then you need to provide a default argument to `n` in your function definition, e.g. `generate_something <- function(n = NA, m, roll)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to make this work, you'd have to include `is.null(x)` in `is.blank()`, but you'd have to evaluate that first, then if it's not `NULL`, evaluate the other conditions:

```r
is.blank <- function(x) is.null(x) || is.na(x) || x == ""

generate_something <- function(n=NULL, m=NULL, roll=NULL) {
  if (is.blank(n)) {
    stop("Missing number of blocks.")
  }
  if (is.blank(m)) {
    stop("Missing M number.")
  }
  if (is.blank(roll) && m > 27) {
    stop("Missing roll where relevant.")
  }
}

generate_something()
#> Error in generate_something(): Missing number of blocks.
generate_something(n=4)
#> Error in generate_something(n = 4): Missing M number.
generate_something(n=4, m=6)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: is there any way for me to modify is.blank() so that I may use it in the same way with the same result you've shown?

Comment: @Andrea I just uploaded an answer that modifies `is.blank()`.

Comment: Thanks @KonradRudolph - I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think @MrFlick has already answered your question. What you are looking is `missing` function and not blank.

```
generate_something <- function(n, m, roll) {
  if (missing(n) || is.blank(n)) {
    stop("Missing number of blocks.")
  }
  if (missing(m) || is.blank(m)) {
    stop("Missing M number.")
  }
  if ((missing(roll) || is.blank(roll)) && m > 27) {
    stop("Missing roll where relevant.")
  }
}

generate_something(m = 34, roll = 1) 

#Error in generate_something(m = 34, roll = 1) : Missing number of blocks.

generate_something(n = 2, roll = 1) 

#Error in generate_something(n = 2, roll = 1) : Missing M number.

generate_something(n = 2, m = 34) 

#Error in generate_something(n = 2, m = 34) : Missing roll where relevant.

generate_something(n = 2, m = 34, roll = 2)
```